# Regex for hashtags is returning not correct number js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the number of hashtags my case is for instagram, wanna make a validation but for some reason the number is appearing 2 instead of 3, I have 3 hashtags there!
Do you guys know why?

```js
let text = "#Visit #test  #test2";
let pattern = /(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/g;
let result = (text.match(pattern)).length;

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `case-insensitive` modifier to your regex.

```js
let text = "#Visit #test  #test2";
let pattern = /(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig; // Added 'i' as the modifier
let result = text.match(pattern).length;

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in another way :

```js
let text = "#Visit #test  #test2"
let result= text.split("#").length - 1

console.log(result)
```

Here you split the text at the hash character, therefore the length will be the number of hashtags - 1.

Comment: That would return a wrong answer for a text without any hashtag..
"Test".split("#").length -> 1

Comment: I thought there would always be a hash character.

Answer (score 0):

1. By using regex **:**

```js
let text = "#Visit #test  #test2";

var count = (text.match(/#/g) || []).length;

console.log(count);
```

2. By using [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method **:**

```js
let text = "#Visit #test  #test2";

console.log(text.split('#').length - 1);
```